# FAILED: TARGET_KERNEL_BINARIES

Tags: android, kernel, android-rom

I'm building an AEX Oreo ROM. Here are the repositories I cloned https://github.com/kegang0619?tab=repositories

---

Device tree = https://github.com/kegang0619/android_device_samsung_j5y17lte
https://github.com/kegang0619/android_device_samsung_exynos7870-common

Vendor tree:= https://github.com/kegang0619/android_vendor_samsung

Kernel Source:= https://github.com/kegang0619/FlareKernel_AOSP_V2

ROM Source:= https://github.com/AospExtended/platform_frameworks_base

---

I have an error saying "FAILED: TARGET_KERNEL_BINARIES"

After a few searches, I thought that must be declared in the BoardConfig.mk of the device tree. But, I couldn't figure out.

Dogbin URL:= https://del.dog/hixepifazo.rb

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you figure it out?